# What branch does a task relate to after check in?

Tags: tfs

My goal is to produce a list of changes going out in a build. I have a branch in TFS for the release build, and a branch for new development. So people are submitting changes to both, where the release branch changes are bug fixes typically. I want to collect all the new items (tasks/bugs) submitted to the release branch, and exclude the items submitted to the development branch. The problem is that the TFS queries give me all tasks together regardless of what branch they apply to and I cannot distinguish what's in the next released vs. what is further out in the development branch and not being released.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

To add more detail. I have items that were checked in with code to form a changeset. This changeset contains code for X branch. I want to query this:

"Give me all items that affected code in the X branch"?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598921.aspx

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have branches already, I want to track "items" relative to the branches.

Comment: The branching guidance will help you in terms of how to set up branching to more easily track movement between branches.

Comment: Viewing the history of a specific branch isn't what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If your engineers are associating the bug/requirement/task with their code on checkin you should be able to query all work items that are between the last released build and the new one.

For each build since the last release get all work items where "Iterated In" equals that build number and join that together. You will probably want to tidy up the result as engineers tend to check in against Tasks and maybe Bugs but the items of most value to you I think would be Requirements & Bugs.

Using this method you should be able to get:

- All bugs fixed in production branch since last release
- All bugs & requirements completed in development between merges to production

This way you can generate both release notes for a release and sync what is done in production against your change control approvals.. or whatever you are up to...

Comment: For the field in TFS are you referring to "Iteration Path"? This only works if the engineers diligently set this correctly which is unlikely. It is not derived from the actual branch check in occurred against. I want to say, "give me all bugs containing code located in the main branch".

Answer (score 0):

If your builds are mapped correctly to the specific folders in each branch, and if you have Associate change sets and Work Items set to true and Label Sources set to true, when you get your build report you will get every check in and any associated workitems since the last build and these will be specific to checkins to the folders in your build workspace

Comment: This sounds great. Could you please elaborate just a little bit. Does this refer to automated builds (which I am current not using) or can this work when building from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, it only works through the team builds, not the visual studio builds sorry.